# How do I correctly remove an array of elements from another array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have an array of elements that I read in from the DOM like this:

```
let delete00To04Am = document.getElementById("time000am400amEveryDay").value;

console.log('delete00To04Am');
//this yields: 1669410000000,1669496400000
```

..

```
delete00To04Am = delete00To04Am.split(',');

console.log('delete00To04Am: ' ,delete00To04Am);
//this yields: delete00To04Am: ['1669410000000', '1669496400000']
```

..

```
timesForAdvert = timesForAdvert.filter((item)=> item !== delete00To04Am )
console.log("timesForAdvert: " ,timesForAdvert);
//this yields: timesForAdvert: [1669482000000, 1669568400000, 1669410000000, 1669496400000]
```

As you can see nothing was removed from the array.
How do I get `timesForAdvert = timesForAdvert.filter((item)=> item !== delete00To04Am )` to work?

Comment: Can you explain your query in briefly? or give me sample array

Comment: I am trying to remove a few elements from the existing array using the values I capture from the DOM.

Comment: Did you check @Majed Badawi answer?

Comment: [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) doesn't mutate the original array. If you _do_ want to edit the array in place, then you'll need to use the [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
const 
  delete00To04Am = ['1669410000000', '1669496400000'],
  timesForAdvert = [1669482000000, 1669568400000, 1669410000000, 1669496400000];

const res = timesForAdvert.filter(item =>
  !delete00To04Am.includes(item.toString())
);

console.log(res);
```

Suggested enhancements to your approach:

```js
const 
  delete00To04Am = '1669410000000,1669496400000',
  timesForAdvert = [1669482000000, 1669568400000, 1669410000000, 1669496400000];

const exclude = delete00To04Am.split(',').map(Number);
const res = timesForAdvert.filter(item => !exclude.includes(item));

console.log(res);
```